# Resolving an ambiguous tag: [mri]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri) tag is currently described as being related to a specific Ruby interpreter:

> Matz's Ruby Interpreter or Ruby MRI (also called CRuby) is the reference implementation of the Ruby programming language named after Ruby creator Yukihiro Matsumoto ("Matz"). Until the specification of the Ruby language in 2011, the MRI implementation was considered the de facto reference.

Unfortunately, this acronym also applies to "Magnetic Resonance Imaging", and a large percentage of content using this tag falls under this definition. (MRI often involves complicated computational data analysis, and so is also appropriate for Stack Overflow.)

I would suggest that these applications should be split into different tags, but there are many possible approaches to accomplishing this, and I don't know how similar issues have been resolved in the past.

Please feel free to point me in the right direction if this is not the correct way to broach this subject.

Comment: Generally you would propose alternative tags for the ambigious one and when they would apply. So, for example, it would seem a [[tag:ruby-mri]] tag would be appropriate for the Ruby related ones.

Comment: Thanks.  That approach and suggested tag makes perfect sense to me.  But, I also wanted to acknowledge that a) I am on the imaging side myself and so am biased, and b) that I am not fully aware of the procedure/consequences of such a change.

Comment: I tend to agree with the consensus, as expressed by @KarlKnechtel and VLAZ, to rename [mri] to [ruby-mri] and to move the non-ruby posts to [medical-imaging] and/or [image-processing].

Comment: I think if we were to do that, we'd need a formal burninate request. We're removing a tag and other tags don't cover the subject, it's not just a disambiguation anymore. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7296893. I still disagree, even though the subject is niche it's distinct, and we certainly allow for niche tags.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My take:

- Tags shouldn't be this short in the first place. It's begging for exactly this sort of confusion. (I just found another example and will post about it separately.) I'd be happy to burn them all, as long as there's some kind of UI that directs people to choose an appropriate tag when they try using the short one.
- A tag about magnetic resonance imaging is not suitable for Stack Overflow. To the extent that such a question could be on topic for Stack Overflow, that question is not *about* magnetic resonance imaging - rather, it's about *an image* that was produced with that technique. Answering on-topic questions can't involve knowing about how these images are created; it could only involve knowing how to work with the image - *as data* - in code. As such, questions about MRI images should instead be tagged [medical-imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/medical-imaging), or according to a file format (e.g. [dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dicom)). Or perhaps even with something more generic such as [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), depending on the circumstances - in most cases, the fact that the image is a medical image *won't be relevant* to solving the problem of processing the image.
- While it's unlikely IMO that anything else that's a valid programming topic could abbreviate to "MRI", it's not worth taking the risk. So the tag as it applies to the Ruby interpreter should be renamed. The suggestion of [ruby-mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-mri) seems fine to me.

Comment: Actually, I'll make one exception for "tags shouldn't be this short": language names. [tag:css] unambiguously refers to Cascading Style Sheets, and the abbreviation "CSS" is essentially treated as if it were the name of the "language" in which the style sheet is written. And of course we have tags like [tag:c], [tag:c++], [tag:c#] etc. that really don't need to be expanded.

Comment: On the other hand, it could be possible to be an expert in processing of MRI images, but not medical imaging more broadly (I would consider myself one). I would follow an MRI tag, but probably not medical imaging. I don't think `image-processing` is a good tag at all, it would rarely be relevant to the MRI Qs I've seen on this site.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- What about [tag:medical-imaging]?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- do you consider it to be a better choice than `image-processing` for MRI-related image processing?

Comment: @Robotnik Ah, yes. Some of the questions I have seen here are not about “image processing” but file type manipulations and the like.

Comment: MRIs do not just produce image data. The data they produce is far more complex, with different weightings, slicings, possible timed data and metadata regarding breathing and heart rate to reconstruct cardiac movement, possibly 3D reconstructions, and far more. I strongly disagree MRI is off topic and should just use image processing, even though many questions may be about that

Comment: @ErikA okay, but where's the part where solving a programming problem related to MRI data would require medical domain knowledge?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel For example, one of the projects I'm aware of is https://fastmri.eu/, where the process of developing an MRI image is sped up by sampling instead of creating a full image, then using machine learning to reconstruct the full image, which was a major programming effort as far as I know, both in tuning the machine and creating the model, which certainly required domain knowledge.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408573/3d-image-visualisation-with-nilearn This has nothing to do with any of the tags you've suggested, yet requires knowledge about the formats to understand they're in different coordinate spaces. Secondly, I'll push back on "medical" here a little bit - I believe most questions here are research questions, not "medical" specifically.

Comment: While there are some specific MRI processing tasks that are modality-specific, they are rarer and tend to be less appropriate for Stack Overflow, as others have mentioned.  So, even though it pains me as a MRI researcher, I tend to agree that a magnetic resonance imaging specific tag is not needed on this site.

Answer (score 8):

There are 103 questions total tagged [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri)

Of those 69 do not have the tag [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) or [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) ([search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri+-ruby+-ruby-on-rails)). Looking through the list, I can spot only one question that seems to be related to Ruby MRI:

- [Use gems with c-extensions in JRuby, or port them to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113158/use-gems-with-c-extensions-in-jruby-or-port-them-to-java)

This makes for up to<sup>1</sup> 35 questions total that are most likely related to Ruby MRI.

---

Proposal:

- New tag [ruby-mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-mri) is created with the existing tag wiki of [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri) and all the Ruby related questions are retagged with it
- <s>The tag wiki of [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri) is changed to be about magnetic resonance imaging</s> (I have been convinced to not keep the tag)
- Clean up the remaining [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri) questions and retagged appropriately<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I have not verified if all of them are indeed related to Ruby MRI. However, if they are being retagged, it should not be a problem to figure out which are or are not in the process.

<sup>2</sup> I have seen cases for [dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dicom), [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), [imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imaging), and [medical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/medical), [medical-imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/medical-imaging). I hope we get some guidelines for which is appropriate where. Suggestions welcome, feel free to edit the post if you have any.

Comment: I don't think we need to keep [tag:mri] for Magnetic resonance imaging. We already have [tag:imaging] and [tag:medical-imaging] which both seem sufficient, leaving the non-programming subject of "MRIs" without a tag, since it doesn't need one (IMO).

Comment: @TylerH I'm not opposed to removing it. But I really don't know. There might be specifics about MRI images that are not applicable to the wider [imaging] tag. If so, it might make sense to keep it. Maybe even rename it to [mri-imaging] so it's more precise. I hope an SME comes in and says "keep it" or "burn it".

Comment: I did ping one DICOM expert in SOCVR to weigh in, there may be one other (I can't remember their name) who could weigh in here who works in DICOM/medical imaging.

Comment: I too work with DICOM, and I feel that there is little to no use for a tag about magnetic resonance imaging here on Stack Overflow. DICOM is already a bit of a niche, so we're talking about a niche for an eventual niche, with no trivial translation to a set of technologies or software. Any question where such a tag is really important is probably a bit too disconnected from programming. There was a time when a SE site for healthcare Informatics was proposed in Area 51, maybe that would have been a place where the tag could have lived.

Comment: Not that there is much harm in the tag existing, considering that we also have other tags which do not translate to specific technologies ([tag:chemistry])

Comment: I see the point in creating new tag [tag:ruby-mri] or renaming existing [tag:mri] to it. But, separate [tag:mri] tag is not needed IMO.

Comment: Perhaps a tag name such as [tag:mri-processing] would be sufficiently non-TLA so as to avoid people using it for anything that happens to be able to be abbreviated MRI, but sufficiently specific to MRIs so as to cover the cases where people want to ask a question specifically about a programming task around processing the output of an magnetic resonance imaging machine.

Answer (score 6):

My opinion:

Tag [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri) for Magnetic Resonance Imaging is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Instead, tags [dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dicom), [medical-imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/medical-imaging), [medical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/medical), [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) etc. can be used where and if applicable.

Off-topic questions should be closed and on-topic questions should be tag-edited.

I agree with [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429337) from @KarlKnechtel; so, I am not repeating those points again in my answer.

A [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429334/resolving-an-ambiguous-tag-mri#comment989750_429337) from @AzorAhai

> On the other hand, it could be possible to be an expert in processing of MRI images, but not medical imaging more broadly (I would consider myself one). I would follow an MRI tag, but probably not medical imaging.

Although, data generated from MRI have some specific complexities, most questions do not ask about those. Most of the times, the questions related to tags I mentioned above explicitly mention related SOP Class. If not and if necessary, we ask OP to mention it explicitly. Combine this with [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429334/resolving-an-ambiguous-tag-mri#comment989745_429336) from @E_Net4, I do not agree creating tags for each medical equipment family like CT, CR, MRI, USG, ECG and so on. Instead, following the tags mentioned above (or other related tags) makes more sense. Traffic is not so high; so, filtering may not be an issue.

I am not aware about MRI feature of Ruby, so I will not say much on that. With reference to the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429336) from @VLAZ, I see the point in creating new tag [ruby-mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-mri) or renaming existing [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri) to it. But, separate [mri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mri) tag is not needed IMO.

Comment: Renaming [mri] -> [ruby-mri] sounds like more work, since only ~40% of the questions in the former are about the latter. Creating a seprarate tag and cleaning up the ~60% remaining [mri] questions should be better. I'm open to what form should that be - should they be all switched to a specific tag (e.g., [medical-imaging]) or something different. I've edited my post appropriately.

Comment: @VLAZ I think there's some consensus that they should be switched to different tags, but the exact tagging will depend on the exact question.