# How do you name tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there any guidelines on how to name tags when you need to create one ?

For example, I asked few questions about a Vue.js datepicker ([this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuepic/vue-datepicker), to be precise).  I created and named its corresponding tag as [vue3-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue3-datepicker).

But there are [several Vue.js 3 datepicker](https://npms.io/search?q=vue3-datepicker) components in the wild.

How would you create a tag for the specific datepicker I am using  so that members using the same component could search for questions/answers related to it ?

Comment: Same these packages are generally referred as? `vendor-package`? I mean, it seems that's exactly what you do in the questions themselves. Sounds like a good strategy to avoid confusion, doesn't it?

Comment: Since the package is @vuepic/vue-datepicker then probably just incorporate that into it: [[tag:vuepic-vue-datepicker]]. It's immediately recognisable and unambiguous.

Comment: We had a good experience with [tag:excel] and [tag:vba]  so I would go for [tag:vue] and [tag:datepicker] /S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll be speaking somewhat generally, because I'm pretty sure we don't actually have a canonical for tag name conventions - but we really should, because there are a lot of bad tag names out there, and the existing FAQ for when to make a tag only states "Propose a good and fitting name for the tag", without defining what a good, fitting name is.

See also: [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/6296561)

### Defacto standards

Just to be clear, there isn't a formal set of guidelines - you can, strictly speaking, name the tag by whatever convention you see fit, provided it doesn't result in an ambiguously defined tag used by multiple very different things. These tags will usually be opposed and removed sooner or later.

However, there are a few defacto standards, which you can find by scrolling through the tag list and looking for patterns. Some of the most common examples:

- Obviously, just the name of the thing is common, when the name of the thing is clear. Most major languages are an example of this ([c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), etc.), as well as a few major frameworks ([reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs), [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), etc.). This might be one of the most commonly used conventions, but if everything could be tagged this easily, the answer would end here.
- `language-library`, as well as many variations with languages, libraries, modules, occasionally operating systems, stdlib components, etc. (Examples: [android-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-datepicker), [docker-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-network), [alexa-smapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-smapi))

  - Occasionally, though primarily with JavaScript (AFAIK), this is redundant and replaced by the language-specific naming convention `library.js` or `libraryjs`, depending on the canonical name of the thing. If the name happens to have a language indicator as part of its original name, that's usually good enough to be a standalone tag. See, for example, [next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js); had the library just been named `next`, it would've had to be disambiguated when named.
- `thing-version` (Example: [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)), though occasionally without a dash (example: [c++23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23)).

  - Note that not all things need versioned tags, and often, it's better to not have any unless there's a very good reason to. What that reason is varies from thing to thing, so I don't want to make any blanket statements.
- `vendor-package`, as [yivi mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429388/how-do-you-name-tags#comment990149_429388). This is one of the single most powerful naming conventions, because most vendors (often people) don't have two identically named libraries. Multiple different people or groups might, but individuals and individual groups usually manage to avoid ambiguities with their own software. (Example: [nlohmann-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlohmann-json))
- Occasionally, a common name for a thing can be an abbreviation - where abbreviations are ambiguous, the very easy naming convention is to use the long form of the name.

  - Example: [the MRI tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429334/6296561) could be disambiguated as [magnetic-resonance-imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-resonance-imaging), plus other tags for the various software that also abbreviates to `MRI`.<sup>1</sup>

### Determining when to disambiguate

There isn't really a one-size-fits-all way to determine when to disambiguate. However, some relevant questions are:

- Is the name of the thing unique enough that it can be used as-is?
- Is the name of the thing an abbreviation that can be expanded?
- Does the name primarily consist of very common words? "Datepicker" is a very good example of a very common word; another way to phrase this question is whether or not the name is just a shortform description of what it does. If the thing it does it common, this is usually a sign a disambiguation is needed
- Are there other very similarly named tags that already exist that could cause ambiguity?

  - Using the example in the question, the existence of [vue-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-datepicker) makes [vue3-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue3-datepicker) ambiguous; it's possible to interpret [vue3-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue3-datepicker) as being a newer version of [vue-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-datepicker), when they could be completely different libraries (spoiler alert: in this case, they're the same tag)
  - As an aside, if the answer to this question is "yes", if the problematic tag or tags aren't scoped sufficiently either, these tags could be (but are not always) candidates for a disambiguation or a burnination, regardless of what you end up naming your tag.
- Is the concept on-topic, or is only a subset of it on-topic? If only a subset is, the tag name might have to be more specific to clarify this before the tag is used. For example, Google is off-topic, but [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) is not.

#### Determining how to disambiguate

Usually, you can pick from the list of common patterns, and that's going to be good enough as long as you manage to identify the variant that offers the least amount of ambiguity. This is hard and done on a per-case basis. The common advice is to search for existing tags, and checking if any of them conflict with your proposed name.

You can also ask around in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you get stuck on the tag name. Maybe also on meta, but I don't think we have a tag for naming help at the moment, so iDunno.

If, for some reason, *none* of the defacto standards work, the only option left is to get creative. Use anything mentioned by the library to find anything that can be used to disambiguate. However, for the most part, you will not have to. When all else fails, you can almost always use `vendor-library`. There are exceptions to this as well, but if `vendor-library` fails because, for example, a `language-library` tag with the same name already exists, the tag needs to be killed in favour of two differently named tags.

For these cases, you can usually go to meta and ask for a disambiguation of the tag (a [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) is usually applicable), and specify the reason for the conflict, and ask for input on new tag names for the two conflicting things.

#### Example: The case in the question

In this case, as mentioned in the comments, the only good option is to use `vendor-library`. However, there is already an ambiguous tag for this library. All three questions on [vue-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-datepicker) is about the same library that you created [vue3-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue3-datepicker) for. I've merged both of them into [vuepic-vue-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuepic-vue-datepicker), so this particular problem has been solved - for now.

#### A sidenote on systemic problems

One of the *major* challenges, if not the single biggest challenge with naming tags is that the system will fight you.

You can have a clearly named tag with a clearly defined  tag wiki, which isn't going to be read. Taking Glide as an example, at one point, the plain [glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide) was used for the Android library, while the tag itself referred to (and had been used multiple times for) [glide-golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide-golang). This is in spite of the tag wiki for [glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide) at the time saying it wasn't for the Android library.

There's a significant number of tags with similar problems; some wikis even state "DO NOT USE" - but they still are, because tag wikis have a design challenge the company doesn't want to solve.

This means that, often, leaving the base name for an ambiguous library name as a tag is a bad idea, because that tag will receive questions for the other, properly-scoped tag. These then have to be edited, which requires work resources. In some of the worse cases, where this isn't picked up and/or the tag doesn't have enough editors around, the tag can be fully hijacked and require a much more complicated removal down the line. There's a reason the burnination backlog is going to take decades to clear without major changes to multiple cleanup and tag management systems.

On top of tag wikis and names not being good, synonyms aren't always good either. It's apparently unclear when a tag is a synonym, and what that tag is a synonym for, so you can have ambiguous synonyms as well. On top of that, the tag recommendation system is also somewhat bad, and occasionally recommends the wrong tag for libraries with the same name. These then get used because "the system must surely be correct" - usually by people who (understandably, given that the company doesn't care about onboarding) don't understand how the often unnecessarily complicated tag system works.

It's a mess - welcome to the tag system on Stack Overflow.

There's nothing we can really do about this as long as the company isn't cooperating with us, so the best we can do is make sure the tag names are as clear as possible from the start, and eliminate problematic tags as early as possible.

### New software and future ambiguities

From time to time, you'll end up making a plain tag that you think is fine, but then later turns out not to be. This happens when new software picks a name they think is nice, but then happens to conflict with the name of an existing and potentially popular software, often in a different area.

Consider, for example, [android-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-glide). There's also [glide-golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide-golang), [groovy-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-glide), [glidejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glidejs), and [php-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-glide), all of which refer to different libraries or software by different people that all do different things. You can also find similar examples by searching the tag list for "datepicker".

If/when this happens, there's only really one thing to do, and that's disambiguate the now ambiguous tag, and make new tags for the software. You can never fully safeguard yourself against future ambiguity, but starting with picking unambiguous names for tags with very common words is a very, very good strategy. Some tags needing cleanup down the line will still happen, even with a good starting tag name, often for unforeseeable reasons out of our control.

### Footnotes

1: Note that the MRI tag in particular is more likely to be axed, but that's a discussion for that question, and does not affect the example.

Comment: That's a thorough and a very elaborated feedback you made. Thank you so much. I tried to add a tag to my questions related to that datepicker according to your feedback and the comments above, but I found someone re-named the tag I used, and it is a perfect name because it clearly and precisely identifies and distinguishes that datepicker from other ones.

Comment: The continued existence of the [tag:python-3.x] tag past [January 1, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) has done considerable damage to the site (in particular, by making it harder to get relevant gold badges and thus narrowing the pool of qualified curators).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That is not the point, and it does not matter. That's a discussion for another question. Regardless of whether it should continue to exist or not, it is  _currently_ an example of a versioned tag naming convention